# Android Emulator (from Android Studio) lagging

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Searched for a solution, didn't find anything helpful.

I have a GTX 970 and an i5 4690k OC 4.2 GHz. 
The Emulator from Android Studio is lagging as hell and I don't know why.

Intel HAXM is installed, 4G Ram is allocated to the Android Device. I just can't find a solution. Btw. I don't think my processor is too bad since I can run 2 VMs at once and the Emulator works fine on my XPS 15 9560 (i7 7700HQ & GTX 1050)

Does anyone have an idea what to do?

Config:

[image]

[image]

Also tried using Software for graphics emulation, much more slower. Btw for reference this runs in the background and doesn't seem to resolve: [image]

The SDK used[image]

CPU Usage:

[image]

Also, I installed the AVD also on the same system on Hackintosh:

CPU: 10% and works smoothly

[image]

Comment: I recommend that you edit your question and provide more details about your emulator image: x86/ARM, Android version, screen resolution, graphics mode (hardware/software), etc.

Comment: Added @CommonsWare

Comment: Can you show the SDK for Pie version what you have downloaded

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of TaskManager->Performance->CPU when emulator is running?

Comment: Added more information @SahilManchanda

Answer (score 4):

Cut the RAM *way* back. There is no Android device of note that has 8GB of RAM. Something in the 1-2GB range should be fine.

Cut the VM heap *way* back. For example, my emulator images use 48-128MB, not 8GB.

If those don't help, experiment with a lower-resolution emulator (e.g., Nexus 4 1280x768) and see if that changes your results.

Comment: None of your options worked.  (Your options were almost the default settings, I upped the RAM etc. so high and wanted to look if it worked)

Comment: @filip: How much system RAM do you have on this machine? Does it look like you are swapping memory a lot when running the emulator?

Comment: I have 16Gb DDR3 Ram @ 1600Hz. How do I see if it is swapping? Here a Screenshot of Task Manager if it's helping: https://imgur.com/a/7tWnczB

Comment: @filip: Well, I don't read what I suspect is German, and I don't use Windows regularly, but that looks like half your system RAM is free, so you aren't swapping. At this point, I'm at a loss as to what may be slowing down your emulator. You might experiment with a third-party emulator (e.g., Genymotion).

Comment: I used genymotion it also laggs

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it! I did a random windows update to Version 1803 and now the emulator works perfectly! Thanks for all your suggestions and answers!

Comment: this merely equals a fresh install, with automatic data migration. I'd suggest to run "disk cleanup > system files" in order to get ~ 20gb of storage back, because it keeps the previous version of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

also think that the RAM settings are at fault ...

in particular the heap size matching the total capacity.

the default settings, which should run smooth(er) are:

- CPU: 4 Cores (while available)
- RAM: 1536MB
- Heap: 384MB

also check background processes once, in particular AntiVirus with on-access scanner, etc. (some people have 2-3 of them installed); one of them is enough and if present, disable it once for a test. the emulator ordinary is much less of a memory hog than Android Studio with Gradle *can* be. if everything fails, the screenshot shows that there is one bank available, which could take 2 DIMM. booting another system from external media might also worth a try, in order to rule out the current OS install. and I also have that "preparing for setup" on one emulator image; that's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I also tried the default settings before tho.. I have AVIRA installed, disabling it didn't help tho. I'm trying it on another OS now on the same System.

Comment: I'm on the same system on my Hackintosh: https://imgur.com/a/EHFV3Dm
Low CPU usage, works smooth as hell.

Comment: @filip glad to hear. unless there is something excessively consuming resources on the other install, I'd guess that the `HAXM` driver didn't install properly or may have improper resource settings. reinstalling it with AntiVirus disabled might spare you from a fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try changing the OpenGL ES Renderer to **Desktop Native OpenGL**
And OpenGL ES API Level to **Renderer Maximum**
This made my emulator very responsive, almost 2x faster.
[Like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXe3x.png)

Also it might be worth mentioning that I set both my camera's to none.