# stuck on "you can finish setting up your AOSP on IA emulator soon " ON android emulator

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator, android-device-manager

when i start android emulator from android device manager i get a screen with this message "you can finish setting up your AOSP on IA emulator soon " after i click on wifi , i can't connect the emulator to internet.
another piece of info that might help i get at first the notification that vanguard is detected disable or uninstall , i disabled before starting the emulator but no success yet.

Comment: You could try to restart the device, and set the DNS in the Network preferences.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT how do i set DNS in what network prefereneces can u expalain plz ?

Comment: It's probably just a coincidence. It just suits me. You can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429292/android-emulator-from-android-studio-lagging, maybe it'll help you.